# Range with decimal place

Tags: ruby, arrays

How can I check a range with decimal place in ruby?

I want to filter results in an array between 9.74 - 9.78 in ruby

```
if (9.74...9.78) == amounts
count += 1
end
```

This seems not to work

Comment: Please edit to clarify.  I think you mean, "I want to determine if a given number, `amount` is within a given range", but you could mean, "I want to determine if all the numbers within a given array `amounts` are within a given range".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this using [*`Range#cover`*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F):

```
if (9.74...9.78).cover? amounts
    count += 1
end
```

Example :

```
p (9.74...9.78).cover? 9.75 # => true
p (9.74...9.78).cover? 9.79 # => false
```

**Update as @m_x suggested**

```
# will give you the element in the range
array.select{ |item| (9.74..9.78).cover? item }
# will give you the element count in the array belongs to the range
array.count{ |item| (9.74..9.78).cover? item }
```

Comment: +1, but can be shortened : `array.count{ |item| (9.74..9.78).cover? item }`

Comment: would this still work if the numbers could have more decimal places such as 9.741773962804002

Comment: yup, i doubted too, but the OP states "I want to filter results in an array..." . Maybe `select` would be even more appropriate.

Comment: amounts are values that are in an array

Comment: @m_x Yes.. Now OP confirmed.. so I changed

Comment: @Phillip-Marsden I think yes, but with floating-point math, I suggest caution :) . Just try a few ones...

Answer (score 2):

Just put the numbers in parentheses and `===`:

```
if ((9.74)...(9.78)) === amounts
  count += 1
end
```

EDIT: While putting the numbers in parenthesis doesn't seem necessary, I'd recommend it anyway to make it clear what is the range and what is the decimal point.